# Can we add files to a zip archive with modified file names

Tags: linux, zip

I want to create a zip archive for some files in folder hierarchy.

for example:
abc.php_0973_890
newone.text_2344_870

I want to have:

abc.php
newone.txt
 in my zip archive. Is there any way for doing this?

Comment: We can not do that as zip doesnot suuport anything like that,
we can use tar for such things as it as options like:
 --transform
which can be used to transform the output filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not do that as zip doesnot suuport anything like that, we can use tar for such things as it as options like: --transform which can be used to transform the output filename